# Webauthn and TLS channel binding

Tags: tls, authentication, web

1. my understanding is that webauthn supports a variety of authentication schemes --not necessarily FIDO2/CTAP ; is that true? if so what is the api at webauthn that provides the hook?
2. TLS channel binding -- again my understanding is that, pki key pairs -- private keys are stored in tpm/secure elements; not necessarily on usb keys ; are there any software based open source implementations?

a) does openssl tls support channel bindings yet? would this translate back to apache (httpd) upgrade to ensure channel binding is secure even after user authentication (eg stolen cookies, session id etc.)

Thanks in advance.